Sanger Method - DNA sequencing
I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding the Sanger method of DNA sequencing. How can you determine the order of the sequence just by the length of the fragment the ddNTP is attached to?
For example, say in our sequence the first base is A - so the ddNTP would be T, but what if randomly the first fragment is very long and the T is at a position that corresponds to the end of the sequence - would we say that A is at the end of the sequence?

Sanger sequencing doesn't use random fragments like many of the high-throughput sequencing techniques. Instead, it uses a series of progressively longer fragments, all of which originated at a dedicated primer site. Because they all have the same origin, the final nucleotide of a particular fragment will be a known distance from that priming site.
Today, PCR amplification is used to produce enough of the template DNA and to specify an arbitrary* location for the priming site. As bases are added to the elongating strand, a fraction will incorporate a fluorescent ddNTP, which terminates that particular fragment. All the other fragments are still elongating and so have the opportunity to incorporate a fluorophore as the next nucleotide.
Each fragment of a particular length should have incorporated the same fluorescent nucleotide. All of the fragments are then passed through a capillary which separates them by size (with enough precision to identify fragments differing in length by a single base pair), and the signal strength of each fluorophore color is recorded at then end of the capillary.
From this trace of fluorescence intensity the sequence of the original template can be reconstructed.

*Mostly, there are still considerations needed around selecting an optimal priming site.

What has PCR to do with Sanger sequencing? PCR hadn’t been invented when the method was introduced.

That's correct, the original Sanger protocol used bulk DNA from bacteriophage ΦX174, then used the fragments from restriction enzymes as primers. Following the advent of PCR the technique could be expanded to samples that otherwise wouldn't contain enough DNA, and allow for a much wider selection of priming site. Now, it's standard to use the products of a PCR reaction as the input for Sanger sequencing. I've edited the answer to clarify that it's the location of the priming site that creates a uniform starting point for elongation.
